# Calculating the amount of heat lost by my home on a cold winter day

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I need to solve the following problem in *Thermal Physics* by Schroeder:

> **Problem 3.12** Estimate the change in the entropy of the universe due to heat escaping from your home on a cold winter day.

I know that (because the temperature outside and inside will remain constant), $$\Delta S = \frac{Q}{T_\textrm{out}} - \frac{Q}{T_\textrm{in}} = Q\frac{T_\textrm{in} - T_\textrm{out}}{T_\textrm{in}T_\textrm{out}},$$ so now what I need to do is figure out what $Q$ is. It's assumed that I don't yet know about blackbody radiation. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don’t you try to estimate the amount of energy that you use for heating? Or you base your estimate on the heat conduction of typical building materials used in your house and the temperature difference between inside and outside.

Comment: Let $T_1$ be the temperature inside and $T_2$ the temperature outside of your home. Wouldn't the entropy change be actually equal to $Q\frac{T_1 - T_2}{T_1 T_2}$? Since your home loses heat that is absorbed by the outside.

Comment: The problem is actually asking for a numerical estimate of Q? From the standpoint of demonstrating your understanding of the physics of the problem, I think that you have already accomplished that by writing down the equation above.

Comment: To quantify this, you need to estimate the convective heat transfer coefficients to the air inside the house and outside the house.  You also need to estimate the resistance of the insulation within the walls.  Then you can calculate the total heat flow based on a temperature difference of say 20 C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using about $10,000$ cubic feet of natural gas corresponds to an energy usage of about $10^{10}$ joules.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the heat content  of the world will increase by the amount of heat you generate by say burning wood in your house, or using an electric fire for heat will cause the power station to burn more fuel to add heat the world up via your home even before it escapes from your home.

Comment: There is no such a thing as heat content.